# Drop being overlapped by textviews React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, spinner, dropdown

Created a form in react native with drop-down spinner and few text view. There is a problem when I click on drop-down spinner, its options are being overlapped by the text views below.

Below is code snippet and also adding screenshot

[image]

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Image
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import DropDown, {
      Select,
      Option,
      OptionList,
      updatePosition
    } from 'react-native-dropdown';
    
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    export default class Corporate extends Component {
    
      //=======navigation optionpane========//
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
        header: null
      };
      //====================================//
    
    
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          canada: '',
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        updatePosition(this.refs['SELECT1']);
        updatePosition(this.refs['OPTIONLIST']);
      }
    
      _getOptionList() {
        return this.refs['OPTIONLIST'];
      }
    
    
      _canada(province) {
    
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          canada: province
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
    
          <View style={styles.container}>
    
            <Image source={require('../logo.jpg')} style={styles.image}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Corporate Sign Up</Text>
    
    
    
    
            <View style={{ }}>
    
              <Select
                
                width={300}
                ref="SELECT1"
                optionListRef={this._getOptionList.bind(this)}
                defaultValue="Select a Province in Canada ..."
                onSelect={this._canada.bind(this)}>
                <Option value={{ id: "alberta" }}>Alberta</Option>
                <Option>British Columbia</Option>
                <Option>Manitoba</Option>
                <Option>New Brunswick</Option>
                <Option>Newfoundland and Labrador</Option>
    
              </Select>
    
    
              <OptionList ref="OPTIONLIST" />
    
    
            </View>
    
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Company"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Email/Employee Id"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Referral Code(Option)"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
            </View>
    
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5}>
              <View style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText} > Submit</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    
    
        )
      }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
    
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
      },
      image: {
        width: 250,
        height: 110
      },
      text: {
        color: "#FFF",
        fontSize: 25
      },
      inputWrap: {
    
        marginVertical: 10,
        height: 40,
        width: 300,
        marginTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
      },
      input: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      },
      button: {
        backgroundColor: "#FF8C00",
        paddingVertical: 15,
        marginVertical: 15,
        marginHorizontal: 120,
        width: 100,
        height: 35,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      buttonText: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 15
      },
    
      set: {
        marginTop: 20
      },
      spinner: {
    
        marginVertical: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
    
      }
    });
```

Comment: in react-native whatever renders after gets higher z-index , giving higher zIndex to <Select /> should solve it.

Comment: What should be the value of zIndex ?

Comment: Setting zIndex does not work, even dropdown is not clickable after setting zIndex